# Erro Request method 'GET' not supported ao realizar update

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Boas colegas. Estou com um erro que ainda não consegui solucionar. Pretendia criar uma funcionalidade na minha aplicação que estou a desenvolver com spring mvc. O objectivo era clicar no botao ou link ele muda o campo estado que aceita apenas dois valores Permitido e Não Permitido de uma tabela chamada Utente para Não permitido. Então primeiramente criei um método na camada DAO para poder usar a query do jpql para realizar o update, o metodo é o seguinte:

```
@Override
    public void interdict() {
        createJpqlQuery("update Utente set estado='Não permitido'");

    }
```

De seguida criei o método na camada service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
    public void interditarUtentes() {
        utenteDAO.interdict();

    }
```

Depois chamei o método da camada service para o controller

```
@PostMapping("/interditar")
    public String interditarUtentes(ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        System.out.println("AQUIIIII");
        service.interditarUtentes();    
        attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Utentes registados interditos com sucesso");
        return "redirect:/utente/listar";   
    }
```

Mas quando chamo o controller pela página retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Tentei usar @RequestMapping onde usei os parâmetros value e method e deu o mesmo erro.

Tentei trocar post por get e também dá outro erro diferente que foi:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update mz.com.centropontoencontro.domain.Utente set estado='Não permitido']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update mz.com.centropontoencontro.domain.Utente set estado='Não permitido']
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update mz.com.centropontoencontro.domain.Utente set estado='Não permitido']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update mz.com.centropontoencontro.domain.Utente set estado='Não permitido']
```

A classe domain do objecto é:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ute_utente")
public class Utente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ute_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ute_nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "ute_datanascimento")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;

    @Column(name = "ute_genero")
    private String genero;

    @Column(name = "ute_naturalidade")
    private String naturalidade;

    @Column(name = "ute_bi")
    private String numeroBi;

    @Column(name = "ute_nomemae")
    private String nomeMae;

    @Column(name = "ute_nomepai")
    private String nomePai;

    @Column(name = "ute_localtrabalho")
    private String localTrabalho;

    @Column(name = "ute_contacto")
    private String contacto;

    @Column(name = "ute_estado")
    private String estado;

    @Column(name = "ute_numeroemps")
    private Long numeroEmprestimos;

    @Column(name = "ute_data_registo", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dataRegisto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ute_instituicaoid")
    private InstituicaoEnsino instituicaoEnsino;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ute_enderecoid")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Endereco endereco;
```

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Fazer POST ao invés de GET, sua controladora está utilizando `@PostMapping`, se quiser utilizar GET altere para `@GetMapping`

Comment: Sugiro fechar a pergunta e criar uma nova, ja que o problema original foi corrigido

Comment: obrigado. Após trocar para @GetMapping lançou um outro erro: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update mz.com.centropontoencontro.domain.Utente set estado='Não permitido']

Comment: Como disse, o problema inicial foi fechado, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é realizar a chamada de um método que apenas aceita `POST` (método marcado como `@PostMapping`) utilizando `GET`.

Caso a idéia seja realmente utilizar `GET`, basta anotar o método como `@GetMapping`.

Link para [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)